# How can integrate the login/registration into a pinax(0.9) projects?

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pinax

I have installed pinax and now I want to integrate some apps. First I would like to start with the login and registration.

I tried to deal with poor documentation of Pinax, therefore I do not know how to start?

How can I do that with pinax 0.9. What do I have to modify?

What would be the general path to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pinax-project-account](https://github.com/pinax/pinax-project-account) first you have to start a project on consol write these

```
$ django-admin.py startproject [your_project_name] --template=https://github.com/pinax/pinax-project-account/zipball/master
```

[your_project_name] replace your own project name. Then you have to install requirements

go to the directory which has requirement.txt file on consol and write

```
pip install --requirement requirements.txt
```

then test your project it will probably works!
Dont forget to add app to INSTALLED_APS